# Spring Boot + Thymeleafe + Vue.js multiproject

Tags: spring-boot, vue.js, thymeleaf

I'm new with Spring Boot and I have a problem with structure and settings for my project. I want to create project with several separate modules, like on image below. One of them ("vue") is for front-end and it will contain HTML, CSS and JS files. Main application will be in another module ("spring"), this module will contain controllers too.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5dJEn.png)

But as I understand Thymeleafe can't see files outside of the "spring" module. Can someone explain me, how to configure my project so that Thymeleafe will use files from "vue" module, please?